# How to disable remapping by a package

Tags: key-bindings, package

I recently used a package that overwrote `C-x C-s` to something other than `save`, causing me to lose a lot of work.  Is there a way I can advise emacs to check for a blacklist of keybindings that it shouldn't allow to be remapped?

Edit:
The package in question is (the otherwise excellent) `atomic-chrome`,  [and this looks to be the offending line](https://github.com/alpha22jp/atomic-chrome/blob/a505f638866f9e7b913784be0dc84f338e9ad449/atomic-chrome.el#L263):

```
(defvar atomic-chrome-edit-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-x C-s") 'atomic-chrome-send-buffer-text)
    (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'atomic-chrome-close-current-buffer)
    map)
  "Keymap for minor mode `atomic-chrome-edit-mode'.")
```

Comment: Can you give more details? What package was it? How did you install it? Melpa? What you are describing is strange. Usually global keybindings don't get remapped by installing a new package.

Comment: Clearly that's a bug in the package you were using.  Have you reported it?  What was it?

Comment: They probably meant `C-c C-s` - please report it to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to advise the `define-key` function and check which key is being bound against a block list:

```lisp
(defvar define-key-block-list
  '("C-x C-s"))

(defun define-key-filter (define-key &rest args)
  (if (cl-member (nth 1 args) define-key-block-list :key 'kbd :test 'equal)
      (message "Blocked %s from being bound" (key-description (nth 1 args)))
    (apply define-key args)))

(advice-add 'define-key :around #'define-key-filter)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") (lambda () (interactive) (message "test")))
;; Blocked C-x C-s from being bound
```